# SAS Calculating rolling sum via EXPAND but output incorrect results

Tags: sas

I employed the following code to output rolling sum for every three year period, while the results are incorrect by adding inexistence number. Please find the code for rolling sum.

```
proc expand data=have out=want;
by firmid ;
convert vcinvest_annual=cum_vc/transformout=(movsum 3 trimleft 2); 
run;
```

Please find the screenshot for the result.

[image]

I find the issue is more frequent when the rolling sum is equal to zero. In order to avoid the hidden number after the decimal point, I used the following code to truncate decimal number.

```
data have;
set have;
put vcinvest_annual=6.4;
run
```

Could someone please inform me of the underlying issue and provide guidance on resolving it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when you use the default [conversion method](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/etsug/15.2/etsug_expand_details13.htm) in `proc expand`. Add `method=none` and it will resolve the issue.

```
proc expand data=have out=want;
by firmid ;
convert vcinvest_annual=cum_vc/ method=none transformout=(movsum 3 trimleft 2); 
run;
```

Example:

```
data have;
    do i = 1 to 10;
        if(1 < i LE 4) then x = 0;
        else x = i;
        output;
    end;

    drop i;
run;

proc expand data=have out=want;
    convert x=x_movsum  / transform=(movsum 3);
    convert x=x_movsum2 / method=none transform=(movsum 3); 
run;
```

```
TIME    x_movsum        x_movsum2   x
0       1               1           1
1       1               1           0
2       1               1           0
3       -2.22045E-16    0           0
4       5               5           5
5       11              11          6
6       18              18          7
7       21              21          8
8       24              24          9
9       27              27         10
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have small non-zero values.  They are small enough that when displayed by the format they appear as zero.  Either you are using a different format to display the new variable than the old variable (BEST12. is used if no format is attached to a numeric variable) or when you add three of them together they are large enough that BEST decides they should be displayed.

Try rounding the input values before passing them to expand.  How many significant digits did you collect for vcinvest_annual?  You seem to be only display 2 decimal places try rounding to 3 (or perhaps 4 or 5) decimal places.

```
data rounded;
  set have;
  vcinvest_annual = round(vcinvest_annual,0.001);
run;
proc expand data=rounded out=want;
  by firmid ;
  convert vcinvest_annual=cum_vc/transformout=(movsum 3 trimleft 2); 
run;
```